# Authenticate user with Google Account iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a login system implemented in my app that works with Facebook (meaning users can login using Facebook). I now wish to implement the same thing except with Google. However, all I can seem to find is authentication through Google+. I wish to authenticate through google accounts and not just Google+ incase users do not have Google+. This would mean authentication through any Google account (Example: Gmail) and not just Google+.

Does anyone know if this is possible in iOS? Like I said, the only thing I found was a guide for google+ [here through Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps)

Thanks!

Comment: intact every accounts in google shares same password for all accounts

Comment: @Shan That's what I thought. However, when I tested this, if the user has never used google+ before, it prompts them to make an account which in my opinion is a poor user experience. That's why I'm looking for any google account authentication, not just Google+